# Changing azure web application logo shown in office 365

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, sharepoint, office365

I'm currently trying to host a web application through azure and making it available to users in office 365 via 'My Apps'.

The user connect to the app site, allows the app to gather data from azure AD, and through the magic of interconnectivity, the app then shows in 'My Apps'.

The problem I'm having is that I need to change the logo/image/tile of the app from the generic 'custom application' one, but I'm having trouble finding any sources telling me how to do this.

The application is built as an ASP.NET Web Application (MVC).

TL;DR: How do i change the tile/icon of a web application hosted in azure, shown in office 365

[This image shows the app i need to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3I7D.png)

Comment: SharePoint isn't an ASP.NET MVC application. Either you have a SharePoint application, in which case use any of the guides that show how to change a site's logo (hint: you can do it from the Administration pages), or it isn't in which case just change your code to use your own images

Comment: My bad, it's a very hot day at the office. I have a web app hosted in azure and connected to an azure AD. When a user browses his apps in office 365, the app is shown but with a default icon/tile. I want to know how I can change the tile to a custom one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to your application's page in the [Azure Management Portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com), then go to the **Configure** tab. On the action bar at the bottom of the screen, there is an option to **Upload Logo**.

[image: Upload Logo screenshot]